# adb shell superuser access without approve from phone

Tags: adb, superuser

I'm running MIUI 3.9.27 on my HTC Desire S.

I accidentally froze my miui launcher (com.miui.home) and after reboot, phone stuck on boot animation, but seems everything running except miuiHome.

I know that for defrosting app from `adb` I should run `adb shell pm enable com.miui.home` but it'd say `Killed` and nothing happen. I read somewhere that I should run it as superuser but when I run `su` adb wait for phone root access approval, and since phone stucked on boot animation I couldn't approve root access.

Is there anyway to access superuser without approving it from phone? or doing pm from recovery?

P.S: I think if I could push LBE Guard data (that adb root access has been granted and remembered) into /data/data it may work but I don't know how I could do this